# Append string to data in ajaxForm "manually"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxform

I have the following string

```
append = "&" + $("#some_form").serialize();
```

that I need to append to the **main_form** data (which sends an image)

```
$("#main_form").ajaxForm({
        target: '#some_target',(...)
```

How can this be done with this form submission method?

Comment: I think you cannot send an image throught Ajax

Comment: what is the data passing from main_form submission ? I don`t get your question completely

Comment: @Cheshire the image upload works.

Comment: @ArunChandranC the data is an input of type file. What I need to do is append to this input, manually, the value of another input from another form